# How to use a tokenizer between filters in solr?

Tags: filter, solr, tokenize

I want to use a schema where the whitespace-tokenizer ist called after one filter and after that all others filters shall be applied:

```
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" tokenizerFactory="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" synonyms="german/synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
<!-- Case insensitive stop word removal.
        add enablePositionIncrements=true in both the index and query
        analyzers to leave a 'gap' for more accurate phrase queries.
-->

<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>

<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
        generateWordParts="1"
        generateNumberParts="1"
        catenateWords="1"
        catenateNumbers="1"
        catenateAll="0"
        splitOnCaseChange="1"
        preserveOriginal="1"
/>
```

Solr only applies the new order between filters, but the tokenizer is called before every filter...

Has anybody a clue?

Best regards, hijolan

Answer (score 2):

Runnig the tokenizer before an filter is default. It's more like this - is the way, solr works. But you can add special kind of filters before the tokenizer, for example the `solr.MappingCharFilterFactory`.

What i'm trying to say: it depends on the filter, if it works before the tokenizer. Look at the CharFilter: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#CharFilterFactories

If you need to "filter" the terms in an more complex way, like `solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory` does, try to use an different tokenizer, like `solr.PatternTokenizerFactory` ([solr.PatternTokenizerFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PatternTokenizerFactory))

Comment: I already tried to use another tokenizer like KeywordTokenizerFactory, and to apply the synonym list after that. All other filters beyond the synonymfilter get additional the Whitespace-Tokenizer assigned. That works and my synonyms are operated correct.
But if I look in the analyzer I get additionally to the splitted strings by whitespace the whole text a second time splitted.

E.g.: Nullam consequat, sem vitae =>
Nullam consequat, sem vitae | Nullam | consequat | sem | vitae

Comment: Not sure, if i understand you right: The `KeywordTokenizerFactory`should handle your word/term without any changes. Probably the `solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory` splits your word/term on whitspaces additional. Take a look at the `solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory`manual: `split on intra-word delimiters (all non alpha-numeric characters).` ...where space is non alpha-numeric